# Call functions in RHS rule in Clips

Tags: function, clips

Is there any way in Clips to create a rule in which the **RHS** is a Function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
CLIPS> (deffunction foo()
         (printout t "The function was called." crlf))
CLIPS> (defrule calls-function
         (trigger)
       =>
         (foo)
       )
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (trigger))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
The function was called.
CLIPS>
```